# What is the command name for auto-formatting in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: keyboard, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

For some reason <kbd>Ctrl+e,d</kbd> won't work anymore so I'm trying to fix it by going into `Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard`, but I'm not sure what command I'm looking for. What is the command name for the auto-formatting command of entire document/project so I can rebind it while keeping my current hotkey config?

Comment: Do you mean Edit.FormatDocument?

Comment: Yeah, but oddly enough it was already assigned, but ctrl+e,d isn't fixing my indentation issues

Comment: Try the menu command: Edit > Advanced > Format Document.

Comment: Using that seems to have fixed the issue, I can now use ctrl+e,d

Comment: Maybe your Shift or Alt key was stuck.